# Python Tkinter GUI - Problem running on different monitors

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming. I just created a new program with python and Tkinter.

The program runs perfectly fine on my PC. Then I created a installer using auto-py-to-exe. That exe runs on my PC extremely well.

My problem is:
When I try running the same program on other PCs, everything works fine but the GUI goes out of screen even at zoomed status. I mean I cant even see some of the buttons as they are not displayed on the screen.

Can someone guide me on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot

I tried different geometry options but didnt work. and I want my program to dynamically adjust to different monitor sizes without any issues.